# Why is CentOS 7 ignoring NETMASK?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, centos7, netmask

I have a networking issue that I eventually tracked down to an incorrect network prefix setting.

`ip addr` is reporting that the current prefix is `/8` when it should be `/24`.

However, when I look in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`, I see `NETMASK` correctly set to `255.255.255.0`:

```
[root@ultravps ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
# Generated by SolusVM
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
GATEWAY=xxx.xxx.xx.x
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

There is no `PREFIX` setting, and when I add `PREFIX`, it fixes the issue. Unfortunately, this is inconvenient because whenever SolusVM reconfigures networking, it reverts back to the above config, dropping the `PREFIX` value.

However, from what I've read, I shouldn't need to specify `PREFIX` when `NETMASK` is set.

Why is CentOS 7 ignoring the `NETMASK` value?

Comment: For one, it's long since deprecated. Just set your PREFIX and get on with life.

Comment: Similar: http://serverfault.com/questions/304949/prefix-versus-netmask